# Simple middleware server for control and monitoring

Tags: java, controls, middleware

I need a server. A simple one, to control a couple of computers. There are already a couple of programs in the lab, that perform some calculation and monitor tasks. They are executed on these computers. So I need a server to control them - to see the real time data from these computers, I want these programs to upload the calculation data to the server, upload also some files, that come together with this data. So the server needs to have a simple database. I also want to alter some of the calculation parameters in the realtime.

Because, you see, I'm a little tired of opening each computer with the terminal, looking at the process, get the files from each of the computers by ftp, put these files in the corresponding folder on the file storage, writing the schedule, when each program should continue it's work.

Maybe there is some middleware, that I can use for such needs? It should be simple and extensible. i thought of writing such server from scratch, it is not a big problem, but I have a severe time shortage and many other things to do.

And it would be cool, that this server would be developer-friendly. So I could just take it's API and write whatever I need.

I'm using Java, so it would be great, that this server would also "understand" Java. ;-) RMI is cool, but because of the network architecture, I'd prefer to use plain TCP/IP for these needs. Becacuse there is always problem with setting up RMI, when there computers are in differed subnetworks.

Thank you very much for your support in advance! Please help me, otherwise my girlfriend would break up with me, because I don't see her often spending most of my time at the lab... ;-(

Comment: So you asked a question and never checked back? If you did, then you should also give some feedback about the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

I am almost finishing a software like that (actually 3 softwares) the server, the clients and the admin that logs into the server and command the clients.
My problem was specific so I had to go for a custom build from scratch (TCP/IP sockets). Its not hard, just write down the protocol.
If RMI doenst help you, then you must consider making your own proto, and you could exten and add new features later.
Maybe Google Protocol Buffers would help you to build your proto
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the two that spring to mind are [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) and [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/). Depends a lot on what you need to do and how you want to go about it. Both are java based.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a problem for which [Bundle-Bee](http://bundle-bee.org/) was [created for](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/herkules/archive/2010/01/28/bundle-bee-transparent-grid-distributed-osgi-computing).